# Why web.config is needed to deploy the react application in IIS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am a beginner to react. We have created a small react application which needs to be deployed on the server (IIS). After googled, I came to know need to add web.config to the react project which will take care of URL routing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Assets" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Why we need to add rewrite rules in web.config to deploy react application in IIS. Can I run react application without `web.config` ?

Comment: You'll need rewrite URL for any other server as well not just IIS. This is because how SPA handles routing. Basically it sends back the html shell that that SPA loads into.

Comment: @penleychan for angular js application i didn't  add any rewrite URL to run it in server.angular is also SPA.

Comment: Hmm pretty sure you need it for angularjs, I remember seting up one for it  otherwise if you refresh you get 404.

Answer (score 0):

The server needs to have the information of the URL routes that you have configured in your project in the absence of which, when you refresh or reload an internal page on your web site, the client will request server for those pages but since they don't exist there you will get an error. Giving the routing info to the Server will help retrieving the right pages and return them back to client.